# Why KL divergence fails to approximate the means of distributions?

Tags: kullback-leibler, approximation, divergence

We have two distributions, $P$ and $Q$ such that $P$ is our input distribution and $Q$ is our target distribution. The formulation of $KL = \mathbb{E}_{P}\left[\log\frac{P}{Q}\right]$ allows us to approximate Q by minimising the expectation.

According to that formulation I've created a small experiment and below there are two plots, the first one is showing the distributions of $P$ and $Q$ after the first step of the optimisation, and the second plot again at the end of the optimisation process.

Here's a more detailed explanation of how the plots where generated.

Let $\theta\sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ be the parameters of interest and $Q\sim\text{softmax}(\mathcal{N}(-2.3, 1.45))$ be our target distribution.

Suppose $X\sim\mathcal{N}(2, 1.3)$ is our data and $P = \text{softmax}(\theta^{T}X)$ is our likelihood.

Then to compute the KL $\sum_{i}^{n}P_{i}*\log(\frac{P_{i}}{Q_{i}})$ loss and thus our goal is to minimise $\hat{\theta} = \arg\max_{\theta}KL$.

Running the optimisation process for 1000 steps we have the following loss

[image]

My question is the following, it seems like the approximation in the beginning and end of optimisation isn't so good in this toy example, why is that ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) If one of the distributions is the target (which usually means a fixed distribution), why are $p$ and $q$ both changing in your plots? 2) It doesn't make sense that the distributions in the second plot minimize the KL divergence. Possible coding error? 3) Could you edit the question to describe what you did in more detail?

Comment: What are you varying to approximate $Q$??

Comment: @user20160 Thanks for the pointers, I think I might have had an error, which I've fixed and I've also updated the OP. But I'm still uncertain as to why now the plots have still bad approximations.

Comment: @whuber I'm varying the parameters of a simple linear predictor $\theta$ * X, I've added the additional details in OP since I've edited with more clarity.

Comment: @KirkWalla these experiments are fantastic. Can you share the code.

Comment: I saw the edit but find your post opaque: how do you connect the dots between "two distributions," "simple linear predictor," and using KL divergence to approximate something?

Comment: Just to say that Ian Goodfellow in 2014-15 had the same confusion just like you and then he wrote the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00160.pdf%EF%BC%89%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E5%9C%A8%E7%AC%AC) Check the page. 24 the direct link is not working.

Comment: Well the KL is supposed to approximate 2 distributions, right? We have our target distribution Q which is a fixed normal random variable with mean and std different from our data X. Now our linear predictor provides a likelihood estimation of data which is then transformed into a distribution P using softmax. Finally KL has to shape P in order to approximate Q. Is that clear enough?

Comment: @whuber, this is an excellent topic and the question is quite clear, he is examined the property of KL divergence reverse and forward one. The method, I am sure the OP will explain the details.

Comment: @Good I do not disagree.  We close ambiguous questions as a favor to everyone: during the period when the original proposer is clarifying the text, it prevents the appearance of conflicting answers due to differing interpretations.  Anyone who has worked to craft a good answer only to be told it wasn't answering the "intended" question understands how important this process is.

Comment: @Kirk I do not follow your last comment, because KL divergence doesn't approximate anything: it merely measures a discrepancy between two distributions.

Comment: @whuber It is quite common in ML to have a model $y_{orig}=f_{\theta}(x)$ where $x$ is some image. Now $y_{orig}$ can be a vector of labels or a matrix distribution if we take $y_{orig} = \text{softmax}(y_{orig})$. Now with the same model we can get another distribution $y_{rot} = \text{softmax}(f_{\theta}(x\prime))$, where $x\prime$ now is the same as $x$ but just rotated at some angle, lets say 25 degrees. Finally, we have 2 distributions $y_{orig}$, $y_{rot}$ which we can feed to KL(y_rot, y_orig). What do you mean KL can't approximate anything, inputs are always 2 distributions.

Comment: whuber means that it’s just a measure. In the same way, accuracy doesn’t approximate anything. All you’ve done is measure a divergence between y_orig and y_rot. Where does the approximation fit in? What value or distribution are you trying to approximate?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I understand it's an asymmetric measure not a distance. I don't recall making such a claim regarding accuracy. According to your understanding what does minimising a divergence imply? According to me it implies you're maximising a "distance" between 2 quantities, a.k.a the approximation between the two quantities must be improving. The distribution of Q is Gaussian with fixed mean and std although I've specified those in the OP. Regarding ur question where does approximation fit? I don't get it, what the purpose of $\theta$ then?

Comment: You're missing my point—this has nothing to do with whether or not KL is a distance. (You and I agree that it's not, but that's irrelevant.) The act of approximation is your choice to use P as a surrogate for Q. Of course, P may approximate Q _poorly_. This is the role of _optimization_, improving your approximation. KL doesn't do the work. It just tells you how far you are. Some optimization process (e.g. iterative scaling, SGD, deterministic annealing) will rely on gradients of the KL function to do the work of improving your approximation.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy thanks for the reply. I think we might be saying the same thing. I agree with everything you've said, here in the simple experiment I've used SGD for optimisation and my question is that in general from what I've seen in this toy experiment and in more realistic scenarios whenever I use KL as the loss I end up with models not converging compared to cross entropy and I'm trying to understand WHY, cause one could argue that C.E. and KL are equivalent under assumptions? My initial question was asking for insight on why models trained with KL don't behave half as good as C.E.?